# How to store data obtained from JTextFields, JComboBox's & JSpinners?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

**Background**: I am creating a GUI for a Cruise company. I have developed a GUI where you may "add a cruise" to the system. I am currently struggling with how to obtain all the data entered and store the data.

I have the following swing components:

1. `JTextField` - To enter Cruise Name
2. `JcomboBox`'s (2) - To select start and end ports
3. `JSpinner`s (2) - To enter cruise start & end date.

**The Problem**:  Upon clicking the button "Add Cruise", I ideally want the new Cruise information to be stored in the cruise ArrayList:

```
public ArrayList <Cruise> cruises;
```

However I am unsure of how to obtain the data from the swing components and adding them to the `ArrayList` when the user clicks "Add Cruise" as not all the swing components are String format. How do I go about this?

How I Created the Components:

1. JTextField

   ```
   Cruisename = new JTextField();
   contentPane2.add(Cruisename);
   Frame2.add(contentPane2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   Frame2.setVisible(true);
   ```
2. JComboBox for Start Port (End Port JComboBox made similarly with same String values)

   ```
   startL = new JComboBox();
   final JComboBox typeList2;
   final String[] typeStrings2 = {
         "", "Tobermory","Oban", "Isle of Mull", "Isle of Harris",
         "Lewis and Harris", "Stornoway", "Skye", "Portree"};
   startL = new JComboBox(typeStrings2);
   ```
3. JSpinners for Start & End Date

   ```
   SpinnerModel model1 = new SpinnerDateModel();
   JSpinner spinner1 = new JSpinner(model1);
   ```

Comment: Can you share more code, such as what you have for your `Cruise` object?

Comment: What does the fact that some of fields are "not in String format" have to do with anything?

Comment: Please provide the code on how you instantiate a combo box or a spinner.

Comment: "I am currently struggling with how to obtain all the data entered and store the data." There are two problems here:

**Enter data**: I am sure you mean making the combo box editable. This is very simple to do.

**Store the data**: Instead of using an `ArrayList`, why not use a combo box model?  Combo box model will be a much better approach (and that is what it is used for to begin with).

Answer (score 2):

For the [JComboBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html), you've provided an Array of Strings. It's stored as an Array of Objects, but you can just cast it back to a String.

```
String foo = (String) myComboBox.getSelectedItem();
```

You can cast it, in this case, since you're storing Strings. If you were storing `Potato`s, you could cast it as:

```
class Potato {
    String name;
    double value;
    String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

Potato bar = (Potato) myComboBox.getSelectedItem();
```

Then, you could pull the value out of the `Potato`:

```
double value = bar.value;
```

For the [JSpinner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html), since you've stored it as a [SpinnerDateModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerDateModel.html), it's up to you whether you want a Date out or a String out. I'll do the date. The String can be inferred from the Date.

```
Date date = ((SpinnerDateModel) spinner1.getModel()).getDate();
```

In most cases, anything you put into a Swing object will be returned as an Object, but you can always cast it to what you know it was when you put it in to get the value you need out.

If you have a different data model, it should operate similarly to the comboBox.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to cast your user's selection to a string since the selection will be of type `Object`. From there, you need to create an instance of a Cruise object and add it to your list.

Your code should resemble something similar to this:

```
public class Cruise
{
    private String cruiseName;
    private String endPort;

    public String getCruiseName()
    {
        return cruiseName;
    }

    public String getEndPort()
    {
        return endPort;
    }

    public void setCruiseName(String iCruiseName)
    {
        if(iCruiseName == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cruise name is null!");
        }

        cruiseName = iCruiseName;
    }

    public void setEndPort(String iEndPort)
    {
        if(iEndPort == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("End port is null!");
        }

        endPort = iEndPort;
    }

}

public class MainClass
{
    private List<Cruise> cruiseList;
    private JComboBox cruiseSelectionCombobox;
    private JTextField cruiseNameField;
    private JButton addCruiseButton;

    public MainClass()
    {
        cruiseList = new ArrayList<Cruise>();
        cruiseSelectionCombobox = new JComboBox(new String[] {"Cozumel port", "Eastern port", "Alaskan port"});
        addCruiseButton = new JButton("Add cruise");
        cruiseNameField = new JTextField();

        registerListener();
    }

    private void registerListener()
    {
        addCruiseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                addCruiseToList();
            }
        });
    }

    private void addCruiseToList()
    {
        String endPort = (String)cruiseSelectionCombobox.getSelectedItem();
        if(endPort == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cruise port is null!");
        }

        String name = cruiseNameField.getText().trim();
        if(name == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cruise name is null!");
        }

        Cruise newCruise = new Cruise();
        newCruise.setCruiseName(name);
        newCruise.setEndPort(endPort);

        cruiseList.add(newCruise);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nit pick: The problem I have with this approach is the need to create a object in order to perform the validation. This might work better if you were using a factory or builder pattern, which was able to do the validation before creating the object, but that's just me

Comment: Do you mean the validation of the objects I get from the respective Swing components? Not sure if I understand what you mean, could you elaborate?

Comment: I mean, I order to validate the information from the UI, you need to create a new instance of Cruise object which seems like more work then it's worth